# Is inversion used in "From this hardship emerged a country"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, subject-verb-inversion

I'd like to know how to analyze the inversion structure below.

Has the prepositional phrase **from this hardship** exchanged its position with the subject **a country that is more capable of coping with inflation**?

Or has **from this hardship** moved to the front, followed by switching around the verb **emerged** and the subject **a country that is more capable of coping with inflation**?

The end result of both proposals seems to be the same. Still, I'd like to know which makes better sense.

> **From this hardship** emerged a country that is more capable of coping with inflation. (This seems to be derived from below.)
>
> A country that is more capable of coping with inflation emerged from this hardship.

Comment: “From this hardship, a country emerged more capable of coping with inflation.” Is also correct

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking how to analyze the inversion structure.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?  It seems rather vague to me...

Comment: Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: How could anyone tell the difference between the two analyses presented? They're syntactically identical. This kind of inversion is common enough with locatives and predicates of existence or motion -- _In the door walked Bill_ -- but there is no way to tell objectively whether the adverb fronted **before** the subject was moved, or whether they occurred simultaneously. Note that Time is not a part of syntactic transformations -- there isn't any "before" or "after" unless one is speaking of the transformational Cycle, and this is a simple sentence so there is no Cycle to speak of.

Answer (score 1):

> Has the prepositional phrase *from this hardship* exchanged its position with the subject *a country that is more capable of coping with inflation*?
>
> Or has *from this hardship* moved to the front, followed by switching around the verb *emerged* and the subject *a country that is more capable of coping with inflation*?

According to [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), the first of those options is correct; in their terminology, subject-dependent inversion is not a mere combination of preposing and postposing, because in some cases subject-dependent inversion is allowed but neither preposing nor postposing are (p. 1386).

To see why, consider these four examples (adapted from p. 1385):

1. A letter that needs to be sent out immediately is up in my room, on the nightstand.
2. * Is up in my room, on the nightstand, a letter that needs to be sent out immediately.
3. (?) Up in my room, on the nightstand, a letter that needs to be sent out immediately is.
4. Up in my room. on the nightstand, is a letter that needs to be sent out immediately.

In (1), you can't move the subject to the end; (2) is incorrect. You also generally can't move "up in my room, on the nightstand" to the start of the sentence; (3) is at best very awkward in most contexts. But you *can* swap the two; (4) is fine.